# How can I add table rows to a table programatically?

Tags: android, view, tablerow

I'm trying to add a custom class that extends table row into a table.

This is the custom class:
    package com.thegame.lunchilicious;

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.text.InputType;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TableLayout; 
import android.widget.TableRow;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class OrderRow extends TableRow {

protected int num;
protected TextView name;
protected TextView cal;
protected TextView price;
protected EditText quantity;
protected int calories;
protected int cost;

public OrderRow(Context context, Item item) {
    super(context);
    this.name = new TextView(context);
    this.cal = new TextView(context);
    this.price = new TextView(context);
    this.quantity = new EditText(context);
    this.setLayoutParams(new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
            LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    this.num = item.getId();
    this.calories = item.getCalories();
    this.cost = item.getCost();
    this.name.setText(item.getName());
    this.cal.setText(item.getCalories() + "");
    this.price.setText(item.getCost() + "");
    name.setLayoutParams(new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
            LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 4f));
    cal.setLayoutParams(new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
            LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1f));
    price.setLayoutParams(new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
            LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1f));
    quantity.setLayoutParams(new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
            LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1f));
    name.setTag("name" + num);
    cal.setTag("cal" + num);
    price.setTag("price" + num);
    quantity.setTag("quantity" + num);
    quantity.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_VARIATION_NORMAL);
    this.addView(name);
    this.addView(cal);
    this.addView(price);
    this.addView(quantity);
}

public OrderRow(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public OrderRow(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}
}
```

This is part of my onCreateView:

```
TableLayout table = (TableLayout) myView.findViewById(R.id.table);
List<OrderRow> rows = new ArrayList<OrderRow>();
for (Item item : items) {

        row = new OrderRow(parentActivity, item);
        rows.add(row);
        table.addView(row);
    }
```

None of the table rows display but everything in the view's xml displays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the Views within your TableRow, you need to use `TableRow.LayoutParams` instead of `TableLayout.LayoutParams`. Like so:

```
name.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(
    TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 4f));
cal.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(
    TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1f));
price.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(
    TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1f));
quantity.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(
    TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1f));
```

Comment: Thank! Now the rows are displaying correctly but when I tap on the editTexts no keyboard pops up.

Comment: Also, have you considered using a ListView instead of dynamically creating a TableLayout? ListViews are made for just this sorta thing. They take care of their own child View creation and scrolling,  and they tend to behave better overall.

Comment: I use ListViews elsewhere in the app but I haven't found a clean way to display columns in a listview so i went with this instead.

Comment: You will have to create a custom Adapter overriding the `getView()` method, but as long as you provide a row layout that is just like what you're creating above, it should work nicely.